# How to replace values by reference in a column on R?

Tags: r

Any player between 1-8 is called "Forward" and between 9-15 "Backward" but those players can be replaced to another with a number higher than 15 and this new player should keep the same status (Forward or Backward). So, How I can assign this status codification by reference? Example

```
data.frame(Player_substituted=c(7,  15,  2,  1,  8,  5, 22, 18),
            Player_substitute=c(22, 18, 16, 17, 20, 19, 21, 23)
            )
#Table
  Player_substituted Player_substitute
                  7                22
                  15               18
                  2                16
                  1                17
                  8                20
                  5                19
                 22                21
                 18                23
```

And the idea is to have an output like :

```
 Player_substituted Player_substitute status_P_sustituted
                  7                22             Forward
                  15               18             Backward
                  2                16             Forward
                  1                17             Forward
                  8                20             Forward
                  5                19             Forward
                 22                21             Forward
                 18                23             Backward
```

That means, for instance, the player 7 is "Forward" and, he was substituted by player 22 so the player 22 is also "Forward". But, player 15 is "Backward" and he was substituted by player 18 so the player 18 is also "Backward"

one option is to use the functions which()to identify index (this is only a draft)

```
#To find index of user with number higher than 15
Index<-which(!Player_substituted%in%1:15)
#To find the user susituted
Index_2<-which(Player_substitute==Player_substituted[Index])
....
```

For sure, this is not the most efficient way. In addition, I need to do that grouping by other variables. Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is `ifelse(df$Player_substituted < 9, "Forward", "Backward")` what you want the new column to be?

Comment: That was my first Idea but , for instance, a player 4 can be replaced by another player higher than 15, let me suppose 25, so the ifelse() in this case does not work since  he will be  a"Backward" when he should be a "Forward" given that he replaced the player4

Comment: Maybe you can give example data and output which shows the difference?

Comment: Thanks a lot for following this @IceCreamToucan. I modified the original output example to be more clear on my need. please let me know if I have been more clear.

Comment: I do not follow the idea exactly but maybe a `left_join` may help you. `df %>% left_join(df, by = c("Player_substituted" = "Player_substitute"))` of course you need to handle with column names but this way you are allowed to apply `group_by`.

Comment: @AurelianoGuedes This is a very good approach. In fact, that solved a high number of cases. I keep having issues for instance when a player with a number higher than 15 is replaced by another with a number higher than 15. For example, if the player 21 leave the match and is replaced by, I don't know, the player 30. But now I have a very small number of cases in comparison to the beginning. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you want to build a chain of substitutions and assign a value to chain members based on the first player in the chain.  We can leverage the `igraph` package to build the substitution chain so we can then assign the correct value to later substitutions.

```
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Player_substituted=c(7,  15,  2,  1,  8,  5, 22, 18),
                 Player_substitute=c(22, 18, 16, 17, 20, 19, 21, 23))

# Generate edges for igraph
edges <- as.character(as.vector(t(df)))

# Generate igraph object
g <- graph(edges)

# Get cluster membership
memb <- clusters(g)$membership

data.frame(Player_substitute = as.numeric(names(memb)), group_id = memb) %>%
  group_by(group_id) %>%
  mutate(status_P_substituted = if_else(first(Player_substitute) < 9, "Forward", "Backward")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  right_join(df, by = "Player_substitute") %>%
  select(Player_substituted, Player_substitute, status_P_substituted)


  Player_substituted Player_substitute status_P_substituted
               <dbl>             <dbl> <chr>               
1                  7                22 Forward             
2                 15                18 Backward            
3                  2                16 Forward             
4                  1                17 Forward             
5                  8                20 Forward             
6                  5                19 Forward             
7                 22                21 Forward             
8                 18                23 Backward
```

Comment: This is exactly the approach I was looking for! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to save the object of your data frame:

   `dat<-data.frame(Player_substituted=c(7,  15,  2,  1,  8,  5, 22, 18)
    Player_substitute=c(22, 18, 16, 17, 20, 19, 21, 23))`
2. Now you can and the values in a new column

   `dat$Player_Substitued<-ifelse(dat$Player_substituted < 9, "Forward", "Backward")`

With "$" you add a new column in the object